# gcm notifcation are not getting on android mobile, type mismatch error on server

Tags: android

Guys i am having issues in implementation of GCM in my android application,
in my application when first time implemented gcm i got notification from server but when i changed the debug key store which caused a new SHA1 and i deleted and recreated a new gcm api from that time i am unable to receive notifications from my custom server.
At my server side , my custom server which i implemented in Microsoft dot net when i send notification to Google it is causing a type mismatch error , i have done all my best to find out what this type mismatch is.

i made  another test app and tried notifications  there and it is working successfully but not not with my application

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please explain in details.. without snippets can't help you.